# convert ascii .dat files to .xml using Matlab (or any other software)

Tags: matlab

I have a set of ascii files with the extension .dat and I need to convert them into a set of .xml files.

Is there anyway to do this with Matlab or any other software.

This is one of the files that I need to convert:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1GI9KuZUKX3TDFCZDVTbzdINUE

Comment: Can you open up the .dat file in notepad or vim and paste an give an example of what the file looks like?

Comment: That link invites me to download the file, it doesn't show me what's in it.  No thanks.

Comment: The file contains lines of tab separated fixed point 4DP numbers.  What XML format are you planning to output these to?
Matlab will very easily read this data and depending on the XML format you are wanting also write it out without much effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Matlab is the weapon of choice for that.

I'd advocate for Python since there are nice XML packages such as lxml. You should be able to parse the dat file easily with open() and readlines().

Answer (score 1):

I've used [XML4MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6268-xml4mat-v2-0) in the past.  It will handle the data conversion into and out of an XML format, but doesn't quite handle actually reading and writing the XML file, so you have to add a little glue code.  The sequence is:

1. Read the dat file into one variable in MATLAB (here I use the variable name Data).  It looks like your file is essentially a table of numbers so that is easy.
2. Use DumpToXML.m and LoadFromXML.m as the glue code to the XML4MAT package that you'll download separately.

   ```
   % function DumpToXML(XMLFileName, Data)
   function DumpToXML(XMLFileName, Data)

       % Generate the text of the XML file.
       XMLData = ['<root>' 10];
       XMLData = [XMLData mat2xml(Data, 'Data', 1)];
       XMLData = [XMLData '</root>' 0];

       % Now output the data.
       fid = fopen(XMLFileName, 'w');
       fprintf(fid, '%s', XMLData);
       fclose(fid);
   end


   % function LoadFromXML(XMLFileName)
   function Data = LoadFromXML(XMLFileName)

       % Open the XML file.
       fid = fopen(XMLFileName, 'r');
       if(fid <= 0)
           error(['Cannot open XML file ' XMLFileName]);
       end
       XMLData = fscanf(fid, '%c', inf);
       fclose(fid);

       % Now get the Data tag.
       DataStartIndex = findstr(XMLData, '<Data');
       % Now find the end.
       DataEndIndex = findstr(XMLData, '</Data>');

       % Extract the strings for this two variable from the string
       % containing the loaded XML file.
       XMLData = XMLData(DataStartIndex:DataEndIndex+6);

       % And turn it back into a variable.
       Data = xml2mat(XMLData);
   end
   ```